# `swift test` produces "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" linker error

Tags: swift, unit-testing, x86-64, xctest, swift-package-manager

I'm currently trying to add support for the Swift Package Manager to a [side-project I've been working on](https://github.com/jakerockland/Swisp/tree/package) and am running into trouble when trying to run the unit tests I have for the project.

When running them within XCode, I have no problem building and running all of my unit tests; however, when I try to run my tests with the package manager using `swift test`, I get the following linker error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: well, which symbols?

Comment: It sounds like your project is being linked with the application target but not the test target.

Comment: @Alexander This is the [full error](https://gist.github.com/jakerockland/e5fd7934fccb1c773025daec5e3ebc06).

Comment: @JAL That does seem to be what's happening but I can't for the life of me figure out why, it seems that I'm following the package manager specification 

Comment: I'm guessing you probably didn't link the test target to the test project

Answer (score 1):

I ended up [figuring out a solution](https://github.com/jakerockland/Swisp/pull/7/) that I'm happy with. I've added a link to the PR here that fixed things, but the general solution was to create a new shared framework target that both my executable and test targets linked to!

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I've hit the exact same issue!